# How do I determine if an array is empty in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, php4

I want to check that an array has no values or that the values in the array are empty. Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "array values is empty"? Useful functions/constructs: `is_array`, `count`, `empty`, `isset`. It all depends on what *exactly* you're trying to test.

Comment: here is an array with no values only keys .i used count and empty but those functions are saying array has values .Array ( [delegate_title] => [delegate_firstname] => [delegate_lastname] => [delegate_jobtitle] => [delegate_email] => [delegate_phone] => [is_bringing_own_laptop] => )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Someday I've learned very smart solution here on SO

```
if(!array_filter($array)) {
  //array contains only empty values
}
```

or even smarter one (if applicable):

```
if(!array_filter($array,'trim')) {
  //array contains only empty values
}
```

Comment: @Vinay it seems empty() is better anyway

Comment: but empty gives me that array has values

Comment: @Vinay what PHP version you're using?

Comment: in local machine php 5 and in server its php 4

Comment: array_filter is really handy! never used it before today, but it solves my problem! thank you!

Answer (score 11):

You want the `empty()` function, here's the documentation of the empty function http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php